# Hide tags without javascript - do it with css?

Tags: javascript, css, tags

is there a way to to this code in CSS?

```
x = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
x[2].style.display = "none";
x[3].style.display = "none";
x[4].style.display = "none";
```

Comment: Do you mean `a { display: none; }` ? :S

Comment: @r1verside The first two aren't hidden.

Comment: Classes? nth-child?

Comment: a {display: none;} add this in css, or add style in you html tag

Comment: Yeah, then `a:nth-child(n+2) { display: none; }` :D

Comment: again, @YatendrasinhJoddha the first two links arent hidden in the code

Comment: @Luca Ohh yeah. My mistake. Thanks :)

Comment: do you want it to be dynamic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `nth-child` selector:

```css
a:nth-child(3), a:nth-child(4), a:nth-child(5) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<a>1</a>
<a>2</a>
<a>3</a>
<a>4</a>
<a>5</a>
<a>6</a>
```

Comment: use the `n+2` to specify the range.

Comment: This will work if the `<a>`s are all placed together as siblings, but not if they're spread around the document.

Comment: @r1verside agreed, but OP hasn't specified this condition anywhere. So holding-off until he does that.

Comment: @BenWest -- Yes. Can't be sure without looking at the HTML.